# after getch() the program ignores the if even after putting 1-6.

Tags: c, if-statement, getch

I have a problem with my code. 
It always ignoring the
if(userDigit<=6 && userDigit>=1).. Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

```
        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            userDigit=getch();
            putch(userDigit);

            if(userDigit<=6 && userDigit>=1)
            {
                //code              
            }
            else
            {
               correct=0;
            }                       
        }

        if(correct == 0)
        {
            printf("wrong");
            correct++;
        }
```

Comment: `getch` is returning character, not digit. So compare it with characters, not digits.

Comment: Character is '6', number is 6.

Answer (score 1):

`getch()` returns a `int` representing the encoded value of the input character, not the digit itself.

Fortunately the C standard allows you to write

```
userDigit = getch() - '0';
```

to transform to the actual numerical value of the digit. Any non-digit input will be outside the range (0 - 9). (For the avoidance of doubt `'0'` is an `int` type in C.)

Naturally that will break your `putch` function (crudely you could transform back by adding `'0'`), but I suspect you have it there for debugging purposes and you can safely remove it.

Comment: Code wouldn't even compile...  -1

Comment: Do I need a coffee?

Comment: Actually `getch()` returns an `int` not a `char` but that `int` is the ASCII code (or UTF-8 or other character code) for what was typed in.

Comment: You try tapping that one out on an iPhone ;-)

Comment: @JeremyP:  Indeed. Furthermore '0' is an `int` type in C

Comment: @JeremyP: Touche. Coffee?

Comment: That's the advantage of a peer reviewed Q & A site. We aim for quality. I'll flog this until it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(userDigit<=6 && userDigit>=1)
```

to

```
if(userDigit<='6' && userDigit>='1')
```

That will work because '0', '1', ... symbols have consequential ASCII codes so the comparisons are valid.

Comment: Any explaination, please?

Comment: Explaination is already done in Bathsheba's answer. '0', '1', ... symbols have consequential codes so the comparisons are valid

Comment: If so, you can remove answer (as question 'is already answered')

Comment: I just think it's a nice way to change the code to work

Comment: No, you should retain an answer. It's good to have a selection to choose from. SO works best that way.

Comment: Yet improving the answer based on feedback is more than welcome.

Comment: Absolutely. I personally don't see a problem with this answer. Although some explanation might be helpful.

Comment: Added some explanation